# How to get a an image of a place from a nearby search from google api with an angular app?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the google places api, and I am trying to get an image for a place of a nearby search. I have tried several variations, and it seems like the documentation is not right, or I am doing something that is not obviously wrong.

I have tried this.

```
 let request2 = {
      key: this.apiKey.getStandardGoogleKey(),
      placeId:"place_id_to_be_used"
    };

    service.getDetails(request2, (results, status )=> this.callback2(results, status));
  }

  callback2(results, status){
    console.log(results);
  }
```

I get this result
[image]

According to the docs, a photos array should include a photo_reference so that I can access an image, but it does not.

I have also tried access the api directly with an http request from angular
using this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

When I do this from postman, I get the photo_reference. But when I do this from my angular app I get a CORS error which looks like this.

[image]

I can get around this locally by adding a plugin to chrome, but the error returned on the production server.

My question is. How do I get a photo_refence from the google places api or another google api for a placeid or another value retrieved from a nearbySearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `photo_reference` property appears in the response of Places API [web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses). As you mentioned, the web service cannot be called directly from the client side JavaScript code due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of web browsers that results in CORS error.

Looking at your screenshot, I would say that the library you used in your code uses a places service of Maps JavaScript API. So you call `getDetails()` method of PlacesService:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService

The callback function receives PlaceResult object:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult

The place result contains an array of PlacePhoto objects:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacePhoto

As you can see the PlacePhoto object has a `getUrl(opts:PhotoOptions)` method:

> Returns the image URL corresponding to the specified options. You must include a PhotoOptions object with at least one of maxWidth or maxHeight specified.

Use this method and you will get a URL of place photo.

I hope this helps!