# Understanding the response from the Google Places Photos API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm making a call to the [Google Place Photos API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) using jquery ajax, and retrieving a response based on a photo reference that was retrieved earlier. The request seems to be going through, but I don't understand the format of the response/how I could convert this into an image.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&key=myKey',
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(imageResponse) {
        console.log("Image response", imageResponse);
    })
```

The output is in the following format...

����JFIF��*ExifII*1Google��XICC_PROFILEHappl scnrRGB XYZ �acspAPPLappl���-appl
rXYZgXYZbXYZ0wtptDchadX,rTRC�gTRC�bTRC�desc�ncprt�Adscm��XYZ tK>�XYZ Zs��&XYZ (W�3XYZ �R�sf32B����&�������������lcurv3mlucenUS$�esES,LdaDK4�deDE,�fiFI(�frFU<�itIT,rnlNL$noNO xptBR(JsvSE*�jaJPkoKR2zhTW2zhCN�Kameran RGB-profiiliRGB-profil f�r Kamera0�0�0� RGB 0�0�0�0�0�0�exOMv�j_ RGB �r_icϏ�Perfil RGB para C�maraRGB-kameraprofilRGB-Profil f�r Kamerasv�g: RGB cϏ�e�N�RGB-beskrivelse til KameraRGB-profiel Camera�t�T�| RGB ��\��|Perfil RGB de C�meraProfilo RGB FotocameraCamera RGB ProfileProfil RVB de l appareil-phototextCopyright 2003 Apple Computer Inc., all rights reserved.descCamera RGB ProfileCamera RGB Profile���

...and so forth for quite a while.

Comment: That looks like a JPEG picture. The JavaScript console is not good at printing binary data but your program shouldn't have any difficulty with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Place Photos client-side service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos) from the JavaScript API's Places Library if you are coding in client-side JavaScript, to avoid CORS errors from same-origin policy.

Otherwise, the images you get from the [Places Photos web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#place_photo_response) can be directly added to `<img>` sources as follows:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&key=YOUR_API_KEY"></img>
```

Also see these related questions:
[Where do I retrieve the photo_reference value to make a Google Places Photos request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750833/where-do-i-retrieve-the-photo-reference-value-to-make-a-google-places-photos-req)
[How to get a an image of a place from a nearby search from google api with an angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022354/how-to-get-a-an-image-of-a-place-from-a-nearby-search-from-google-api-with-an-an)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging this question for two days, searching for the way to fetch correctly with cors to Google Places Api (Photos) https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Little did I know, damn, all of that was a completely wrong approach. Fetch is not required at all!

```js
...
let checkedPhoto = spot.photos[0].photo_reference;
checkedPhoto = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&photoreference=${checkedPhoto}&key=${apiKey}`;
...
```

It's still black magic, as it is not clear how the string like this one: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&photoreference=${checkedPhoto}&key=${apiKey}`

is turned into something like this `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMbYnOpzH_paZWB2UNUob07yY18tjLTtkzHTSMR=s1600-w400` inside img's src attribute?